# Subtract 2 values from one another within 1 column after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am very sorry if this is a very basic question but unfortunately, I'm failing miserably at figuring out the solution.

I need to subtract the first value within a column (in this case column 8 in my df) from the last value & divide this by a number (e.g. 60) after having applied groupby to my pandas df to get one value per id. The final output would ideally look something like this:

```
id     
1     1523
2     1644
```

I have the actual equation which works on its own when applied to the entire column of the df:

```
(df.iloc[-1,8] - df.iloc[0,8])/60
```

However I fail to combine this part with the groupby function. Among others, I tried apply, which doesn't work.

```
df.groupby(['id']).apply((df.iloc[-1,8] - df.iloc[0,8])/60)
```

I also tried creating a function with the equation part and then do apply(func)but so far none of my attempts have worked. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [204]: df
Out[204]:
   id  val
0   1   12
1   1   13
2   1   19
3   2   20
4   2   30
5   2   40

In [205]: df.groupby(['id'])['val'].agg(lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])/60)
Out[205]:
id
1    0.116667
2    0.333333
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I just tried it but when I do I get a lengthy KeyError: -1 Error message (Not sure if it helps posting the entire long error message, can do if helpful). I checked and my id is int64 & col_name is float64, could this be a problem?

Comment: My mistake, I tried the first version and didn't realize it had been edited already, this solution works like a charm!!!